# Typesetting Hoare triples - padding

Tags: math-mode, symbols, parentheses

I'm trying to typeset a Hoare triple, which is used for reasoning about program correctness. In the text I'm referring to, they look something like this:

[image: Hoare triple]

I'm aware the `stmaryrd` package includes relevant commands, so I've tried something like this:

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Hoare{\llparenthesis}{\rrparenthesis}
% ...
\[
    \Hoare*{x > 0} P \Hoare*{y \cdot y < x}
\]
```

Unfortunately, this gives me a `Missing delimiter (. inserted). \Hoare*{x > 0}` error. If I remove the asterisk from the command, it compiles but the spacing looks *off*:

[image: Attempt 1]

Notice how close the parentheses are to the contents of the pre and post conditions. How should I go about improving this?

Comment: `\llparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis` are not “growing delimiters”: they're only available at a single size.

Comment: @egreg That's interesting to know, but I thought the growing delimiters simply changed height (which I'm not too fussed about, it's more the space between the contents and the delimiters I want). Are there visually similar commands from another package I could use instead which would qualify as "growing delimiters"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols `\llparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis` are not “growing delimiters” and are only available at standard size.

I suggest a different syntax, in order to cope with the spacing of the middle term:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand\Hoaretriple[3]{%
  \llparenthesis\,#1\,\rrparenthesis
  \mathrel{#2}\nolinebreak 
  \llparenthesis\,#3\,\rrparenthesis
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Hoaretriple{x > 0}{ P }{y \cdot y < x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like having a command to represent and entire Hoare triple, seems more semantic than the original approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could fix the spacing manually by inserting [some command](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Spacing_in_math_mode#/Reference_guide) for it. Either by inserting the space in your `\Hoare` definition like I did or directly in the formula.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Hoare{\,\llparenthesis\,}{\,\rrparenthesis\,}
\begin{document}
\[
    \Hoare{x > 0} P \Hoare{y \cdot y < x}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for linking that documentation! I was using horrible hacks like `\text{ }` to try and get around this, before.